# Cmake cannot find environment variable

Tags: cmake, hevc

I'm building OpenHEVC (https://github.com/OpenHEVC/openHEVC) with cmake on windows 7 to a VS2010 project.

In the CMakeLists.txt at the root directory, I find the line:

```
include_directories(. ${SDL_INCLUDE_DIR} wrapper_hm/src/Lib)
```

The "${SDL_INCLUDE_DIR}" I think should be the SDL library(http://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php).

My problem is, after downloading SDL library and setting up a new environment variable called "SDL_INCLUDE_DIR" Containing SDL's path (I can "echo %SDL_INCLUDE_DIR%"  in a commandline).  CMake just keeps giving me this (even after restart Cmake):

'''
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
SDL_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Pure265/openHEVC-master/openHEVC-master
   used as include directory in directory C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Pure265/openHEVC-master/openHEVC-master/wrapper_hm

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
'''

I'm confused why cmake can't find the environment variable. 
(
I'm new to Cmake, But I checked it here : http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables
That ${SDL_INCLUDE_DIR} should be reflected to the env variables.
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${SDL_INCLUDE_DIR}` is not an environment variable. It is simply a CMake variable that probably gets set in FindSDL.cmake script. You can see that because environment variables have $ENV{variable_name} sintax.

You should install a development version of SDL library. If you look into FindSDL.cmake script you will see where the script searches for header and lib files. As far as I can tell you have to set SDLDIR environment variable to point to the root folder of SDL library.

Comment: Yes, it works after adding the SDLDIR env var. But can you tell me which script is the FindSDL.cmake?

Comment: Find scripts are located in Modules sub directory where you have installed cmake.

Comment: Find it. So, Cmake provides built-in scripts for people to add popular libraries into a CMake project package easily.  Thanks for your help Domen.